# How do I render and return a view as pdf

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf, ironpdf

So I'm trying to add a new endpoint to my controller which can return the html response of another endpoint at pdf.  The reason for this is deprecate a 3rd party service which involves all kinds of other problems.

I've found a library called IronPDF which seems to do the job, but I'm now struggling to get the html of the original endpoint.  It looks something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController() : base() { }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    public IActionResult IndexPdf()
    {
        ViewResult view = Index() as ViewResult;
        HtmlToPdf renderer = new HtmlToPdf();

        // How do I get the html content of view as a string here?
        string html = ??

        PdfDocument pdf = renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(html);
        
        using (var stream = pdf.Stream)
        {
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "Index.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the html of the ViewResult?

This is just an example, I'm hoping to adapt it to handle dynamic pages in future.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

IronPdf just released extensions that help in rendering web application view and page content to PDF. Please use the [IronPdf.Extensions.Mvc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf.Extensions.Mvc.Core) package for ASP.NET MVC Core. This package only serve as an extension. The [IronPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf) package is still needed to render Razor Views to PDFs.

For Example:
Models

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In the HomeController file, use the `RenderRazorViewToPdf` method and pass IRazorViewRenderer, the path to our "Persons.cshtml," and the List that contains the required data.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Persons()
{
    var persons = new List<Person>
    {
    new Person { Name = "Alice", Title = "Mrs.", Description = "Software Engineer" },
    new Person { Name = "Bob", Title = "Mr.", Description = "Software Engineer" },
    new Person { Name = "Charlie", Title = "Mr.", Description = "Software Engineer" }
    };
    if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post.Method)
    {
        ChromePdfRenderer renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();

        // Render Razor view to PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = renderer.RenderRazorViewToPdf(_viewRenderService, "Views/Home/Persons.cshtml", persons);
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline");

        // Output PDF document
        return File(pdf.BinaryData, "application/pdf", "razorViewToPdf.pdf");
    }
    return View(persons);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try as below in your controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexPdf()
    {
        using StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        IView view = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, "Index",true).View??default!;
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view, ViewData, TempData, sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());
        await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);
        var content = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

        ChromePdfRenderer renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();

        PdfDocument pdf = renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(content);
        return File(pdf.Stream, "application/pdf", "Index.pdf");
        

    }
```

inject ICompositeViewEngine into your controller:

```
private readonly ICompositeViewEngine _viewEngine;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine)
        {
            .......
            _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Notice:

1,`HtmlToPdf` is obsolote,you could try with `ChromePdfRenderer`

2,You have to input full address for your css files,or the css won't work

[image]

the content string is OK,I checked with `return Ok(content)`:

[image]

3,You could just try with

```
renderer.RenderUrlAsPdfAsync("targeturl");
```

directly,without getting the html of the ViewResult.